# Integrating Google Spreadsheets in my website

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been looking at the Google Drive Platform for Web here : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk , But I am not sure if it suits my requirement. Here is what I want to do

After the users login on my site, I want to show a spreadsheet from my Google Drive to only the logged in users. Now if they need to be connected to their account on my website, that's fine with me. All I want is when I create their account, they create some kind of authentication token with google account, and now they are able to see all the spreadsheets that I share with them from google drive account.

Please suggest what is the good option for me to achieve this ?

**Update :** There could be a few spreadsheets, each per user, and I don't want a user to see the spreadsheet that is not for him, the spreadsheets should not all be public. I will show the spreadsheet to the user that belongs to him, & ideally I would want him not login to his google account when he logs into my web app.

Comment: Since its a file that you own you might want to look into using a service account. You don't want to access there Google Drive accounts so there is no reason to use the normal OAuth2 flow for this.   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: A service account cannot normally access files in your Drive account. If you took this approach, you would need to share the any files with the service account. imho a better approach would be to hardcode or store a refresh token. Need more information on how the users would consume the Drive file.